# Self-capacitance of electrodes in capacitors

Tags: capacitance

I thought about a way in which we could increase self-capacitance of electrodes in a dielectric capacitors. Is it possible to create an internal electric field in each electrode which would have an opposite direction from the electric field between electrodes (in the dielectric separator)? So each electron which is transferred to one of the electrodes would experience two opposite electric forces equal to each other. Would it allow to pack more space charge in each electrode? One possibility could be a geometry of an electrodes. We may use many microneedles separated by dielectric matrix with sharp points turned to opposite side from the another electrode. In this case electric field will increase to external part of the capacitor, away from other electrode. Another possibility may resemble the principle used in thermopowers, when two dissimilar metals are alloyed to create a built-in electric field. And again this build-in electric field has to be directed away from the field between the electrodes. And this built-in field needs to be uniform throughout the entire electrode.

Comment: The electric field is 0 inside of a conductor.

Comment: Is it zero when we push some electrons inside a conductor or inside the plate of a charged capacitor?

Comment: INside the plate of a capacitor is a conductor, so yes, the field is 0 there.  Between the plates is an insulator, so the electric field is non-zero there.  And technically I lied.  The electric field is 0 inside an ideal conductor.  Practically speaking everything has *some* parasitic capacitance, even a wire.  However, these effects on a reasonable wire are *very* short lived (picoseconds.. .nanoseconds at most), so they are unlikely to be meaningful for the topic at hand.

Comment: One way to look at it.  In a mostly-ideal conductor, if you manage to get an electric field going, it will apply a force to electrons within that volume.  Those electrons will move, and the result of that movement will drive the electric field to zero.  Very fast.